# Files turned into folders on external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, network-shares

I have a networked hard drive where I like to store audio/video/software and all sorts of other files for my house. While the software files are all intact and working, many of my video and audio files have been turned into folders! Can anyone explain why this is happening, how I can prevent it, and if it is possible to revert these "folders" back into files. Thanks much!

An example of what the folders are named:
"Highschool Graduation.avi",
"Birthday party.avi",
"Somesong.mp3"

The HDD is connected to a Linksys E4200 router (Firmware Version: 2.0.37). This is how the HDD is networked.

Comment: what folder names do you see? provide a sample, please

Comment: Does this mean you no longer require an answer?

Comment: I meant to say "done" to providing a sample. I am still in need of an answer

Comment: Which OS? Have you tried using another system/OS to view the files on the HDD? Have you run a thorough anti-virus scan? Also, what happens when you try to open these so-called 'folders'? Maybe only the icons have got messed up?

Comment: What do you see if you open one of these folders?

Comment: There are no viruses on my computer as far as I can tell. If I open the folders, there is nothing inside. They are empty folders. I don't have another operating system to check the files with unfortunately.

Comment: @Karan, I was able to load Ubuntu and the files still show up as folders. The folders have nothing in them.

Comment: And if you visit them in the Linux CLI and use 'ls -l' do they still show directories?  If so, sounds like it's hosed.  I don't know that you can blame it on the router, but I'm not sure what else would have caused it.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? Having the exact same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I was never able to find a solution for this problem unfortunately. Luckily I had backups and so I abandoned searching for a solution.